# Windows 10 file explorer; Open file in background using keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

How can I open a file in the Windows 10 file explorer so that the file explorer stays "on top"/"in focus"?
I want a keyboard shortcut.

Solution using mouse also welcome, but not enough for accepted answer.
Likewise, a "this is currently not supported" with some source/motivation/credibility also welcome, because then I can stop thinking about it.

I have tried the usual suspects, ie ctrl/alt/shift + enter, and every second order combo of them. No luck.

My use case is I often want to open a bunch of files after each other, and it would be nice to not have to switch the file explorer back into focus after opening each file. I am aware that I can open several files at once by selecting/highlighting all and hitting enter, but this only work as long as they are the same file type and in the same folder.

Comment: While I'm unsure if Windows natively supports this, Stardock's [WindowsFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowfx/) does have the feature to pin any window on top. If Windows does natively support this via a key combo, you could use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)